# Getting Facebook Profile Picture in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am building an android app and have successfully integrated Facebook login as the only form of registration and login. I am trying to work out the best way of getting the users profile picture, i have had allow at the developer docs - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture/, however i am not sure how to handle the response, by that i mean how do i actually get the image in the response, is it sent via a bitmap or as a url link, i am not quite sure.

Here is the code the docs provide for getting the profile picture

```
    /* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}/picture",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to perform a GraphRequest like the Docs say but this is how you do so.
Use Facebook's `ProfilePictureView` in your XML layout.

*XML Layout*

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
        android:id="@+id/myProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
```

*Activity/Fragment Code*

```
ProfilePictureView profilePic = (ProfilePictureView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.myProfilePic);
GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse response) {
        if (user != null) {
            // set the profile picture using their Facebook ID
            profilePic.setProfileId(user.optString("id"));
        }
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you that works great, i was wondering do you know how to make the pic circular rather than square?

Comment: No problem! As for your next question, in short: you can't. Not without third party help or implementing it yourself (not recommended). It's not easy but if you hunt around you might find something on GitHub that can do it.

Comment: Is there any reason that this might not work for facebook pages?  Is it because it's `profile` ID? and a page is not necessarily a profile?